# How to set the environment variables in CMAKE？

Tags: cmake, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to use Cmake to manage the dependencies of the Fortran and C code when I compiled the spectral solver. But it seems that Cmake cannot find the compiler although I have downloaded the Fortran and GCC already. This is the error I am getting. I hope there is someone who can tell me how to solve it.

[the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCDwH.jpg)

```
`CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompiler.cmake:58 (set_property):
  set_property could not find CACHE variable CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER.  Perhaps
  it has not yet been created.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineFortranCompiler.cmake:96 (_cmake_find_compiler)
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (project)


-- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompiler.cmake:58 (set_property):
  set_property could not find CACHE variable CMAKE_C_COMPILER.  Perhaps it
  has not yet been created.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:65 (_cmake_find_compiler)
  CMakeLists.txt:109 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:109 (project):
  No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "FC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER to the full
  path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:109 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.`
```

[CMakeLists.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKWGp.jpg)

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. What exactly did you download and install? How did you install it? Are you able to call your compilers from the command line?

Comment: @VladimirF I wanna install an open source software, DAMASK using Ubuntu. There are some auxiliary software and solvers required to be installed first, among of which is Cmake. Now I have installed CMake. But when I further complie the solver, it shows an error as listed above. I can find the file of the compiler located but haven‘t call them cuz I don’t know how to run it....I leave this installation instruction (https://damask.mpie.de/bin/view/Installation/CMake)  and hope you can give me some advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So are you able o run the compiler from the command line? Is it able to compile simple programs?

Comment: @VladimirF  I have run a simple program and it works. So it seems not the problem of the compilers. Here, I additionally provide a related code of the CMakeLists.txt and hope there are some information... and I made a check that I cannot find the environment variables about compilers in Ubuntu. Is it normal? Thanks!

Comment: CMake keeps the build configuration in cache files. Delete the file "CMakeCache.txt" and the directory "CMakeFiles" to "reset" the build configuration. Then, define the environment variables `CC` and `FC` before running CMake. On linux, this would be `export CC=/the/path/to/gcc` and `export FC=/the/path/to/gfortran` (1. change "/the/path" to the actual path and 2. if gcc and gfortran are in the search path, you can juste use `export CC=gcc` and `export FC=gfortran`.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl   Is 'the path' the path where the gfortran and gcc are? Generally, they are in the path '/usr/bin/...'. right? I made a try based on your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. The error I am getting is same to the previous...

Comment: Did you remove the CMake cache files? What is your OS? In the case of linux, you mention that you have downloaded the compilers. Typically, one should use the package manager to install such software. CMake detects the compilers of the distribution automatically and there should not be an error unless your setup is unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You need set the env variables. I used the following steps:

1:  vim ~/.bashrc (to set the env variables)

2:  Add the following statements
`export CC=/usr/bin/gcc` (the path basically) and `export FC=/usr/bin/gfortran`

3 - Also make sure your path to PETSC_DIR and PETSC_ARCH is defined, add the following statements too, `export PETSC_DIR = /path/to/petsc` and `export PETSC_ARCH = gfortran`

4 - save and close the file

5 - Run this on command line - to read and execute the bash script `source ~/.bashrc`